# using recaptcha with external form submit url

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I'm trying to use recaptcha to prevent spam on my form that submits to a salesforce url.
The recaptcha instructions say to include the verification functionality in a my internal form-checking. Because the form is submitted to salesforce though, I'm not sure where this code should go...or how to work around submitting the form responses to salesforce if the captcha is entered correctly, and how to re-display the form if it isn't. help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that the form's action takes the user to an external site upon submission, you either need to check the captcha with javascript/ajax, or create a man-in-the-middle page to handle validation and redirection (if everything is valid). Both will give you the ability to kick the user back to the form if something isn't right.

Comment: How do i re-direct? Sorry if that's a stupid question. the contact form is some .inc file so there isn't just a straight URL to redirect it to.

Comment: If you want the "file-in-the-middle" approach, you'll need to change the form's action to point to a new file (presumably a php file). In that file, you can process the $_POST variables, verify and validate all the form data, and then (if everything is okay), redirect them to wherever the form was supposed to go to.

Answer (score 0):

just save cookie to temp file, and resubmit form with curl and set cookies with previous temp file